# Duolingo-like interface in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I am a beginner to Swift and UIKit. I am building an iOS app for a school project and I want one of its views to contain a few words displayed like the words in Duolingo lessons are: [example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJPeV.png)

How can I do that?

Comment: That's a custom inferface, so you would have to cook your own. You might be able to start using a token field, but I'm not sure https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/fields-and-labels/token-fields/

Comment: You can use some github repo - https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView .   https://github.com/zekunyan/TTGTagCollectionView .  https://github.com/OskarZhang/TagListView

Comment: @sohanvanani thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the number of the buttons is changing.
and also, the button's size is changing with title.

So I recommend you learning UICollectionView.(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview).

Comment: I'm taking a look at that right now! Thanks for the advice!